# Rails Resource Restful Routes Helper functions and nil oject error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, routes

I am getting an error when trying to use the resource route helper functions

```
    <%= link_to_remote "Delete", {
        :method => :delete, 
        :url=> phone_numbers_url(phone_number_display.id), 
        :update => "section_phone"
        }%>
```

and in my routes i have

```
       map.resources :phone_numbers
```

I get the following error

```
 You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
 The error occurred while evaluating nil.to_sym
```

When I use

```
:url=> phone_numbers_url(:id => phone_number_display.id)
```

I no longer get the error but I get the unrestful url of

```
 http://localhost:3000/phone_numbers?id=1
```

I do no understand this error as phone_number_display.id is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the singular version of the route:

```
phone_number_url(phone_number_display)
```

Answer (score 1):

There should not be a need to enclose the trailing arguments in {}, since they'll be transformed into a Hash anyway. See the [api for link_to_remote](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/link_to_remote). I don't know if that's what is causing the problem, but it's the first thing I'd try.

```
    <%= link_to_remote "Delete",
            :method => :delete, 
            :url=> phone_numbers_url(phone_number_display.id), 
            :update => "section_phone"
            %>
```

After that, if it's still not working, I'd look at the `phone_numbers_url(phone_number_display.id)` part, to check that I'm getting what I expect.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be preferable to use `phone_numbers_`**path**`(phone_number_display.id)` as this will give you the relative path "`/phone_numbers?id=1`" instead of the full `http://localhost.../..` path.

Answer (score 0):

if you've just created this route, you might need to restart your mongrel.

also you might want to run rake routes to double check the named route.

Comment: yup I did that, it does not seem to be the issue